# How to render transparent text with alpha channel in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using `pygame.font.Font.render()` to render some text. I'd like the text to be translucent, ie have an alpha value other than 255, so I tried passing a color argument with an alpha value (eg `(255, 0, 0, 150)`) as the color argument for `pygame.font.Font.render()` but it didn't have any effect. I also tried using `pygame.Surface.convert_alpha()` on the resulting Surface object, but that didn't do anything either. Any ideas?

Comment: How about an alpha of 0? Will that still show the image?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Yes, because the alpha channel is ignored when rendering text. Please read the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font) module, the alpha channel of the text color is not taken into account when rendering a text, but see [`pygame.font.Font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont):

> Antialiased images are rendered to 24-bit RGB images. If the background is transparent a pixel alpha will be included.

and [`pygame.Surface.set_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)

> Changed in pygame 2.0: per-surface alpha can be combined with per-pixel alpha.

Hence it is completely sufficient to set the transparency after rendering the text with `set_alpha`. This even works for anti-aliased text:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 150)

text_surf = font.render('test text', True, (255, 0, 0))
text_surf.set_alpha(127)

window.blit(text_surf, (x, y))
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentText](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentText#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 150)

text_surf = font.render('test text', True, (255, 0, 0))
text_surf.set_alpha(127)

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

By using the [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module, you can use a transparent color directly when creating a text surface:

```py
ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 150)

text_surf2, text_rect2 = ft_font.render('test text', (255, 0, 0, 128))
window.blit(text_surf2, (x, y))
```

Or if you are rendering the text directly onto a surface:

```py
ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 150)

ft_font.render_to(window, (x, y), 'test text', (255, 0, 0, 128))
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentFreeTypeText](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-TransparentFreeTypeText#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ft_font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 150)

text_surf2, text_rect2 = ft_font.render('test text', (255, 0, 0, 128))

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    
    text_rect = ft_font.get_rect('test text')
    text_rect.center = (window.get_width() // 2, window.get_height() // 2 - 70)
    ft_font.render_to(window, text_rect.topleft, 'test text', (255, 0, 0, 128))
    
    text_rect2.center = (window.get_width() // 2, window.get_height() // 2 + 70)
    window.blit(text_surf2, text_rect2)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

See also [Text and font](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_text_and_font.md)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why, but after some experimentation I have discovered that the surface created with `font.render` cannot have it's alpha value changed.  Just blit that surface to another surface, and change the alpha value of the new surface.

```
textsurface=font.render('Test', True, (0, 0, 0))
surface=pygame.Surface((100, 30))
surface.fill((255, 255, 255))
surface.blit(textsurface, pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10))
surface.set_alpha(50)
window.blit(surface, pygame.Rect(0, 30, 10, 10))
```

Comment: This works, and answers my question, but now the surf around the text is black! I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: @jellyberg don't forget to fill the surface that you change the alpha value of with white before you blit the text onto it.

Comment: I'm actually using some pixel art of a beach as a background, so I filled it yellow. I've got some really nifty looking damage numbers now, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's annoying. Wish there was an easier way.

Comment: @jellyberg If you want to remove the color around the text, the code should be 
`surface.blit(textsurface, pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 10), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the transparency of the entire surface using a individual alpha value.
Use `surf=pygame.Surface((size,pygame.SRCALPHA)`. Now if you change the alpha value by setting `surf.set_alpha(alpha)` of the screen, the surface around the text wont be black anymore.