# Why text display for 2 seconds in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Text wchich I display is displaying for only around 2 sec. I want that it will display while I click to other area

```
elif msg[0:7] == 'YOU WIN' and Message_id == '200':
    print('You Win')
    textSurface = font.render('You Win', True, (0, 0, 0))
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf = pygame.font.render('You Win', True, (0, 0, 0))
    TextRect = textSurface.get_rect()
    TextRect.center = ((600 / 2), (700 // 2))
    surface.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    grid.draw(surface)
    pygame.display.flip()
    break
```

Comment: Do you mean like a simple pop-up message that disappears after 2 seconds?  Can you explain a bit more how the "click" in another area works with it?

Comment: Yes, like a pop-up but the background of the text is transparent. This is tic tac toe game. If I click in choosen area on the board display X or O. If I click of the bootom of window the player start the game

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be drawn permanently, you need to draw it in the application loop. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Create the text surface at initialization:

```py
winTextSurf = font.render('You Win', True, (0, 0, 0))
winTextRect = winTextSurf.get_rect(topleft = (600 // 2, 700 // 2)
```

Add a variable that indicates the text needs to be drawn:

```py
drawWinText = Fasle
```

Set the variable if the text needs to be drawn:

```py
elif msg[0:7] == 'YOU WIN' and Message_id == '200':
    drawWinText = True
    break
```

When you no longer want the text to be drawn, you need to reset the value.

```py
drawWinText = False
```

Draw the text in the main application loop depending on the status of `drawWinText`:

```py
while run:

    # [...]

    if drawWinText:
        surface.blit(winTextSurf, winTextRect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

See the answers to question [Python - Pygame - rendering translucent text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620109/how-to-render-transparent-text-with-alpha-channel-in-pygame/64552616#64552616) for how to draw transparent text.