# How draw button in window in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code in my program, if I click on the choosen area that the server start new game. How to do it that in this place will be button or a square with text 'new game'?

```
with socket.create_connection((SERVER, PORT)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname="localhost") as client:
        session_id = None
        while True:
            #command = str(input("Podaj komendę"))
            #command = translate_pos_to_number(pos[0] // 200, pos[1] // 200)
            czy_wyjsc = True
            while czy_wyjsc:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:  # [0] Jeśli lewy przycisk myszki jest kliknięty
                            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                            print(pos[0] // 200, pos[1] // 200)
                            czy_wyjsc = False
                            break
                surface.fill((20, 189, 172))

                grid.draw(surface)

                pygame.display.flip()

            if (pos[0] // 200 == 1, pos[1] // 200 == 3):
                command = "start"
                if command == "start":
                    login = np.random.randint(100, 999)
                    msg_start = f'To:SER\r\nLogin:{login}\r\nContent-length:5\r\nMessage:START\r\n\r\n'
                    client.sendall(msg_start.encode())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a button in pygame, you first need to add a font to your python program and then, create a label to show some text in that button:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 30)
label = font.render("SomeText", 1, [COLOR])
```

After that, you need to create a rectangle on your screen:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(YOUR_SCREEN, YOUR_COLOR ,(X_POS,Y_POS,X_SIZE,Y_SIZE),1)
YOUR_SCREEN.blit(label,(X_POS,Y_POS))
```

And after that, you only need to add the collision in your pygame events:

```py
for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if events.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if pygame.Rect(X_POS,Y_POS,X_SIZE,Y_SIZE).collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    Your_Function() #Your_Function is the function you want to execute when clicking the button.
```

I hope I helped you ! (and if you have any questions, feel free to ask)

Comment: In your example, how does the text show up on the screen?

Comment: The text shows up on the screen with the `YOUR_SCREEN.blit(label, (X_POS, Y_POS))`

Comment: It should work if you already have a pygame working screen.

Comment: I see. I think you missed the variable assignment and took the liberty to add it to your answer.

Comment: Hi, I add following code ` font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 30)
        label = font.render("New Game", 1, (0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), (200, 600, 200, 100), 1)
        surface.blit(label, (225,620))` but the background is transparent. How do it that it will be white bacground and text on it?

Comment: Hello kamil, to put the background, you simply have to modify the draw rect line like that: `pygame.draw.rect(YOUR_SCREEN, YOUR_COLOR ,(X_POS,Y_POS,X_SIZE,Y_SIZE))` (I just removed ",1" from the line)

Comment: just do that: `pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), (200, 600, 200, 100))`

Comment: Thanks, could you also read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459547/why-text-display-for-2-seconds-in-pygame

Comment: of course, i'll take a look, if I understand, it's the next part of your program, am I right ?

Comment: Sorry, I need more informations to help you with the other question.

Comment: please add comment what you need in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459547/why-text-display-for-2-seconds-in-pygame

Comment: I can't, I don't have enough reputation :(  and honestly, I don't really know how I could solve your new issue just by the snippet you posted