# can I create a rectangular surface and draw a text over that and blit these objects together in pygame

Tags: python, text, pygame, draw

I need to create a rectangular object and draw a text with respect to the rectangular object and blit these items together in the screen.
I am using pygame library to create the game.I am new to this pygame programming.  Can someone suggest me  method if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text surface is a surface object like any other surface. Render the text:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 80)
text_surf = font.render('test text', True, (255, 0, 0))
```

Create a surface and `blit` the text surface on it:

```py
rect_surf = pygame.Surface((400, 100))
rect_surf.fill((0, 128, 255))
rect_surf.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = rect_surf.get_rect().center))
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 80)
text_surf = font.render('test text', True, (255, 0, 0))

rect_surf = pygame.Surface((400, 100))
rect_surf.fill((0, 128, 255))
rect_surf.blit(text_surf, text_surf.get_rect(center = rect_surf.get_rect().center))

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(rect_surf, rect_surf.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

See alos:

- [Python display text with font & color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077644/python-display-text-with-font-color/64487335#64487335)
- [Python - Pygame - rendering translucent text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620109/how-to-render-transparent-text-with-alpha-channel-in-pygame/64552616#64552616)
- [python library pygame: centering text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982907/python-library-pygame-centering-text)